# Android : Error set margin programmatically : Overlapping

Tags: android

I am rtrying to increase the margin in case there is no image for the specific Question.

I able to increase the margin from the bottom, but the listview and options are overlapping.

**Code**

```
img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)tvOptiontitle.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 170); 
tvOptiontitle.setLayoutParams(params);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)listviewoptions.getLayoutParams();
params1.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 130); 
tvOptiontitle.setLayoutParams(params1);
```

**XML**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstviewoptionAptitude"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnPrevQues"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnPrevQues"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnNextQues"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" >

</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtOptionTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lstviewoptionAptitude"
   android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lstviewoptionAptitude"
    android:text="Option Title"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

**OutPut:**

[image]

Comment: Try to set top margin for listview.

Comment: add image how to show your layout

Comment: I want space btween the textview and listview

Comment: @Ircover I tried adding margin top didnt work

Comment: Space Between "Identfy the error" And listview

Comment: Try to add `android:layout_below = @+id/txtOptionTitle` rule to listview.

Comment: @Ircover : Nope its not helping